# python-nvd3 missing xAxis ticks

Tags: python, d3.js, python-nvd3

I create a multibar chart in python with `python-nvd3`.

**The problem** is that only every second X-Axis tick/label is showing up on the chart.

I generate is the chart in python before passing it through to a flask-template.

The problem is described in another SO posts too, but the solution is directed at Angular and does not point to a way that I can pass the attribute in python to the chart before I create it.

---

[StackOverflow solution 1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101352/multibar-chart-with-nvd3-d3-only-shows-labels-for-every-other-tick-on-the-x-ax)

[StackOverflow solution 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882662/angularjs-nvd3-multibar-chart-xaxis-tick-not-showing)

---

The solution suggests setting the attribute `.reduceXTicks(true)` but my problem is that I can't see a way to set this custom attribute in python.

This is what the chart looks like.

[image]

This is how I generate the chart, and also my X and Y axis data below:

```
fchart = multiBarChart(name='f_multibarchart', width=1000, height=400, x_axis_format=None, color_category="category10")

xdata ['510', '125', '630', '625', '650', '1000', '805', '515', '610', '800']
ydata1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ydata2 [1, 17, 23, 1, 29, 0, 0, 2, 0, 13]

fchart.add_serie(name="Full", y=ydata1, x=xdata)
fchart.add_serie(name="Low", y=ydata2, x=xdata)
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

Setting `reduceXTicks(false)` **did not work** for me.

I found that the opacity of a missing X tick was set to `0`, So what I did was to use the `add_chart_extras()` function to push the opacity to `1` for all ticks.

```
fchart = multiBarChart(name='f_multibarchart', width=1000, height=400, x_axis_format=None, color_category="category10")
extras = "d3.selectAll('#f_multibarchart text').style('opacity', '1');"
fchart.add_chart_extras(extras)
```

[image]